# Angular - Should ngDisabled work on any HTML item?

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app i have a flag icon using the code:

```
<i ng-click="detail.flag()" class="fi-flag"></i>
```

I also have a boolean variable that I'd like to use to disable this.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
<i ng-disabled="showDuplicate" ng-click="detail.flag()" class="fi-flag"></i>
```

and

```
<div ng-disabled="showDuplicate"><i ng-click="detail.flag()" class="fi-flag"></i></div>
```

Any ideas why they dont work?

Thanks.

Comment: so you want to disable the icon on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngDisabled** - This directive sets the **disabled** attribute on the element if the expression inside ngDisabled evaluates to truthy.

Elements that can receive the **disabled** attribute include `<button>`, `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>` and `<fieldset>`.

That's why it won't work on `<i>` (or `<div>`) element.

Comment: I tried wrapping my `<i>` in a `<fieldset>` and that didn't work. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nosiyaligi/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

As others mentioned, `ng-disabled` is specific for some tags only. I assume that you want to disable clicking on the element when your variable is false, you can do it this way

```
<i ng-click="showDuplicate && detail.flag()" class="fi-flag"></i>
```

This is called short circuiting an expression, if `showDuplicate` is true, the next term will be evaluated which is `detail.flag()` if it is false, it will not continue evaluating the next term since `false && true` is still `false` so it will not bother evaluating the next terms

Though you should be styling the element if you disable something, so you should add a class that says it is disabled and style it accordingly

```
<i ng-class='{disabled: showDuplicate}' ng-click="showDuplicate && detail.flag()" class="fi-flag"></i>
```

in your css:

```
.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.8 /* ? it's up to you how you want to style it*/
}
```

Comment: Interesting method. It does work however i see an error in the console - `angular.js:13550 Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assign a value to a non l-value`

Comment: Hi @userMod2, I added a demo

Answer (score 0):

The answer is correct, you cannot use ng-disable with icon html tag.
I tried somthing like that:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoController as detail">

  <i ng-disabled="detail.showDuplicate" ng-click="detail.flag()" class="fa fa-flag">test</i>
  <button ng-disabled="detail.showDuplicate" ng-click="detail.flag()" class="fa fa-flag"></button>

</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0DBXJ4o9hmdtep8PM4Wc?p=catalogue

I hope it helps.